# Text editor in Java with sample functions for desktop application

Tags: java, text, editor, bold, italic

I have a project, I'm creating an application in Java and I need text editor with sample functions (Bold, Italic, Size, Align, Undo, Redo).

So is there a class in Java for this purpose or a tutorial to show how to develop it?

I tried to style text in a jTextPane but when I change a word in bold, the whole text become in bold.

I want just to stylize the selected text only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started: [Editor based on JTextPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/EditorbasedonJTextPane.htm)

[image]

---

Or this tutorial: [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/TextSamplerDemoMetal.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Tutorial's TextComponentDemo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) illustrates many features such as undo/redo, styling selected text and binding key strokes to editing actions.